# Handling subdomains in appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

The redirects intuitive to us are from say http://www.x.appspot.com to http://www.x.appspot.com/y.

What if i want to handle subdomains in my application like http://www.x.appspot.com to http://admin.x.appspot.com/

Do we need to treat them as separate applications?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you actually can not have one app-assigned url handled by two applications: the `x.appspot.com` is assigned to only one application.

However you can easily handle different subdomains, e.g. `www.x.appspot.com` and `admin.x.appspot.com` via [modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/). Note that modules are a different instances with different codebase within same application sharing all stateful services (database, memcache, task queues, etc..).

See [routing requests to modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing) for details on how to map subdomains or even paths to distinct modules.

Comment: Have split my file into modules but having an issue.The issue is the following:- my default module uses static_dir's like images and stylesheets and the yaml file of my admin module also uses the same - but it does not show up!..all that occurs is 404 errors of not having found static dirs. What is the way forward?